# Update standard object fields from custom object

Tags: apex, visualforce, soql, metadata, dml

is it possible to update number of fields of standard object from custom object using apex and visualforce. We cannot call the API within the org. But however could we use SOQL for DML transaction with APEX? If yes, how can we handle checkbox fields?

Comment: Can you clarify your question? As I read it the answer is simply "yes" and checkboxes are just Booleans.

Answer (score 1):

@Curious, Yes we can copy custom object records to standard object, and as @keith mentioned checkbox can be retrieved or assigned by Boolean value(true/false). Query custom object for all fields you want to copy in standard object, make sure data type of fields against which you will copy the custom field data will be same. You will get a list of records which you can parse and map it to appropriate fields in standard object. Rest depends on your requirement.